# Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#

the following C# code return xml resualt from the url site and load to dataset

```
   string a="http://trackandtrace.champ.aero/CargoTrackE/trackHandler?awbNumber=07121988842&forCarrier=ET-V2";
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(a);
   ds.ReadXml(r);
```

but it displays error "Unable to connect to the remote server"
however it works when I use the url directly on the browser. I have browse the net for similar problem but none of them solve my problem.

can you please help me?

thank you

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I can see 5 data tables created within the data set and some rows being populated as well. Are you sure there are o other connectivity issues involved?

Comment: I have checked firewall, it is off, what do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very problem and finally found a solution. I had to add a configuration to the web.config to tell it where to find the default proxy. This is because the client ID that my app pool is using doesn't have security rights to find it on the system that it is running on. So, it's trying to go to the url directly rather than being routed through the proxy thereby preventing it from connecting. In my situation, our IIS server uses a script for it's proxy but this is also the solution needed if you have a proxy server.

**For scripted proxies:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy scriptLocation="http://pac.MyDomain.com/" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**For Proxy Servers:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress ="http://contoso:8080" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

There are other options with the proxy element that may help you as well including: bypasslocal and usesystemdefault but I'm not entirely sure what they do.